# Keyboard shortcut to change the behavior of function keys?

Tags: macos, system-settings

Is there a shortcut for toggling the behavior of the function keys between standard and the media functions printed on them?

I know I can do this in the Preferences, but it would be great to achieve this quickly from the keyboard.

Comment: I want to know this too.. The fn key is just too far away for those F8-F12 keys. Maybe not keyboard shortcuts, but something easier than fn+F12

Comment: I also want to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__DoublePressModifier__ KeyCode::FN, KeyCode::FN, KeyCode::VK_CONFIG_TOGGLE_flipfkeys</autogen>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>flipfkeys</name>
    <identifier vk_config="true">flipfkeys</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_DOWN, KeyCode::F1</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_UP, KeyCode::F2</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::EXPOSE_ALL, KeyCode::F3</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::LAUNCHPAD, KeyCode::F4</autogen>
    <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::KEYBOARDLIGHT_LOW, KeyCode::F5</autogen>
    <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::KEYBOARDLIGHT_HIGH, KeyCode::F6</autogen>
    <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PREV, KeyCode::F7</autogen>
    <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PLAY, KeyCode::F8</autogen>
    <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_NEXT, KeyCode::F9</autogen>
    <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_MUTE, KeyCode::F10</autogen>
    <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_DOWN, KeyCode::F11</autogen>
    <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_UP, KeyCode::F12</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F1, KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_DOWN</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F2, KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_UP</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F3, KeyCode::EXPOSE_ALL</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F4, KeyCode::LAUNCHPAD</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToConsumer__ KeyCode::F5, ConsumerKeyCode::KEYBOARDLIGHT_LOW</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToConsumer__ KeyCode::F6, ConsumerKeyCode::KEYBOARDLIGHT_HIGH</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToConsumer__ KeyCode::F7, ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PREV</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToConsumer__ KeyCode::F8, ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PLAY</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToConsumer__ KeyCode::F9, ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_NEXT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToConsumer__ KeyCode::F10, ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_MUTE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToConsumer__ KeyCode::F11, ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_DOWN</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToConsumer__ KeyCode::F12, ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_UP</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

It makes pressing fn twice toggle between using the F-keys as normal function keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Palua](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/palua/id431494195?mt=12). It not only lets you customize the keyboard shortcut, but also lets you choose which applications use which behavior. Best $0.99 I've ever spent.